# cloudify 2.7 locator NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS

Tags: cloudify

I am using the cloudify(version 2.7),when I try to develop a recipe,just a simple command(`java -jar some.jar`),the events grid display "Service Instance non-responsive",and the lifcycle restart again and again,but when I add the lifecycle locator

`locator {
            NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS
        }`

it is ok!
I want to know how it works, I read the [`example recipe`](https://github.com/CloudifySource/cloudify-recipes) on the github, and they don't have the `locator lifecycle`,what are they speciled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Cloudify assumes that a recipe will launch a process and that process should stay alive. If the process shuts down, this is assumed to be a crash and the process is restarted. This is typical for server type applications.

If your use case is different, you can add the locator element. The locator tells Cloudify which process should be monitored. The NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS keyword tells Cloudify that no process should be monitored - it is equivalent to returning an empty list ('[]')

Comment: but most of the example recipe don't contain  `locator lifecycle`, what does the cloudify monitor ?

Comment: By default, Cloudify monitors the process launched by the 'start' lifecycle event. But if you want to monitor something else, you need to use locator.