# How to stop service without restart

Tags: cloudify

I have deployed an "helloworld" service on cloudify 2.7 and OpenStack cloud. I would stop the service tomcat without the service is being restarted.

So, in the cloudify shell I have execute:

**cloudify@default> connect cloudify-manager-1_IP
Connected successfully
cloudify@default> use-application helloworld
Using application helloworld
cloudify@helloworld> invoke tomcat cloudify:start-maintenance-mode 60
Invocation results:
1: OK from instance #1@tomcat_IP, Result: agent failure detection disabled successfully for a period of 60 minutes
invocation completed successfully**

At this point, I have connected via ssh into the tomcat VM and ran:

**CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop**

In the CATALINA_HOME/log/catalina.out I can see that the app server is being stopped and immediately restarted!

So, what should I do in order to stop the app server and restart it only when I decide to restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintenance mode in Cloudify 2.7 is used to prevent the system from starting a new VM if a service VM has failed.

What you are looking for is to prevent Cloudify from auto-healing a process - Cloudify checks for the liveness of the configured process, and if it dies, it executes the 'start' lifecycle again.

In your case, the monitored process can change, since you will be restarting it manually. So you should not use the default process monitoring. There is a similar question here: [cloudify 2.7 locator NO_PROCESS_LOCATORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542694/cloudify-2-7-locator-no-process-locators)